# Include Content in csproj with a wildcard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

First the problem I'm trying to solve.  I work on a large team and we are constantly having merge conflicts on our web.csproj file.  The solution I was trying to implement was including content files using a wild card.

I'm trying to include all files in a directory in my web.csproj file like so.

```
<Content Include="Areas\Public\Client\**\*.js" />
<Content Include="Areas\Public\Client\**\*.html" />
<Content Include="Areas\Public\Client\**\*css" />
```

This works great at first glance.  I can see all files matching these patterns in visual studio.  The problem is, if someone deletes a files from Visual Studio, the IDE then enumerates ALL files in the csproj file and removes my wildcard lines above.

Have any of you solved this problem or have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug in the logic behind handling removal of files. I would consider [filing a report](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: @sophros bug filed...
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3138974/wildcard-support-in-a-csproj-file-gets-removed-when-i-exclude-delete-a-file-using-visual-studio-solution-explorer

Comment: Great. If you want to have it fixed it would be best to encourage people to vote on the bug. If the votes are above certain threshold it will be looked at and fixed.

Comment: @bluetoft, Martin`s point of view should be right. I have a similar problem before in Visual Studio 2015 & 2017. So I voted that report. Besides, my personal understanding of this question is that we use wildcard to include files to Visual Studio, then we delete one file via VS, VS maybe not know which file was deleted, so VS will enumerates all files. The reverse channel seems to be unsupported.

Comment: My workaround is that delete the file from windows explorer not Visual Studio. This method will be a bit cumbersome, but not broken the wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in VS 2015 without loosing the functionality to add/rename/move/etc. items **and** keep the wildcards.

The handling of globbing in project files is only impelmented by the [new CPS-based project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system) in VS 2017, which is not (yet) used for "classic" .NET / ASP.NET projects.

There are ways to add the Content items during the build using globbing patterns (using custom targets) but these will not show up in the solution explorer (which is okay for auto-generated files)

Comment: Thanks but I'm using VS 2015.  I don't know that this helps.

Comment: Yes I'm telling you it isn't possible. I'll edit to make it clear.